# React Hooks clear inputs after submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I started playing with Hooks and I have a useState object with multiple inputs. What I'd like to understand is how to clear the input value after submitting the form.

On the sumbit function I `setInput({ Input1: "", Input2: "" });` and this actually cleans the object values but not the input values.

Also, not sure why `console.log(input);` appears more than once.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({ Input1: "", Input2: "" });
  const [button, setButton] = useState("Button");
  console.log(input);

  const _handleChange = e => {
    setInput({ ...input, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  function _handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInput({ Input1: "", Input2: "" });
    setButton("Submitted");
    setTimeout(() => setButton("Button"), 1000);
    console.log("Submitted");
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={_handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type={"text"}
        placeholder={"Input1"}
        name={"Input1"}
        onChange={_handleChange}
      />
      <input
        type={"text"}
        placeholder={"Input2"}
        name={"Input2"}
        onChange={_handleChange}
      />
      <button text="Save" type="submit">
        {button}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `input` is **an uncontrolled component**, it doesn't aware of the state `input.Input1` that handled by `_handleChange`.

Try adding a `value` prop to it.

> See [controlled vs uncontrolled component.](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components)

```
<input value={input.Input1} onChange={_handleChange} />
```

[image: Edit mystifying-liskov-vmpx8]

---

Moreover, the log appears twice on `_handleSubmit` because you changing the state twice:

1. Batched set state - causes a single render and first log.

```
setInput({ Input1: '', Input2: '' });
setButton('Submitted');
```

2. You set a `timeout` which changes the state after `1000ms` - causes a single render and second log.

```
setTimeout(() => setButton('Button'), 1000);
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you - I was refactoring a class component to use hooks and `value` was there before, deleted by mistake.